# Two Dimensional Databases

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema, olap

I'm trying to create structure for my data.

I have numbers from 0 to 180 - let's call it `A`, and I have another set of numbers from 0 to 180 - let's call it `B`.

`A` and `B` represent coordinates on a map.

I want to be able to store data at the intersection of `A` and `B`.

At the intersection there will be two values: `UserName`, `ID`.

For example, if I searched for all values when `A=5 AND B=9`
there will be:

```
UserName=john ID=4564
UserName=jack ID=4548
...
etc a large number of values
```

The point of all this is to store ((john)) in a certain place `(A=5, B=9)`
and to get all people that are with ((john)) by only knowing `(A=5,B=9)`.

I have no idea how the data will be represented.

I thought about dimensional database but I read that it is for business analysis (OLAP).

Is there other dimensional database that I can use? Is dimensional database the right solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the Geometry type?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Points do not have intersections. Btw. you might be interested in postgresql range queries. https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/73/Range-types-pgopen-2012.pdf

Comment: If you have tools to access objects via ActiveX, then you can use Microsoft Excel for this purpose.  It can emulate 3-D datasets (as sheet, row, column) that are persistable.  I'm sure other spreadsheet products can be used in this way as well.

Comment: Forget about 'dimensional database' - this is something completely different. If you want to store three values (A,B and the value at it's intersection), just use a table with three columns. If you want something more specific indicate which database you will be using.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The amount of data are huge and I want to reach to the specific data that lies at the intersection in the fastest way possible, I have a little experience with databases but I don't think that table with three columns will be efficient in search

Comment: @kalebora, please explain what kind of searches you need to perform. The simple search `SELECT Value WHERE A=X AND B=Y` would be quite efficient with a simple table with three columns `A`, `B`, `Value` and index on `(A, B)`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov The search is the same as you explained but there will be many values ; when 'A=X AND B=Y' there will be huge values at this intersection ...Values like  UserID:X UserName:X , UserID:XX UserName:XX  ... how it can be done in this approach?

Comment: @kalebora, I don't understand your question. If you have not one, but many values, then you'll have many columns instead of one `Value`.... Kind of obvious... You'd better describe in your question what kind of data you want to store, with some examples. Edit your question, rather than adding it in comments.

Comment: Is user Id related to user name? i.e. does id 4564 always represent John? If so then you still need a table of three columns. If not then you need a table with four columns. How 'huge' is the data? how many combinations of A and B are there? Is there anything more than ID and name stored at each point?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question is related to OLAP.

I would make the schema something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Coordinates
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A] [int] NOT NULL,
    [B] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Primary key on `ID`, indexes on `A` and `B` or one index on `(A,B)` including `UserID`.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL
    ...
    more columns with information about a user as needed
    ...
)
```

Primary key on `ID`. Other indexes as required to help find users (such as index on `UserName` to look for users by their UserName).

To find all users at given coordinates `(A=5,B=9)`:

```
SELECT
    Users.ID
    ,Users.UserName
FROM
    Coordinates
    INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID = Coordinates.UserID
WHERE
    Coordinates.A = 5 AND
    Coordinates.B = 9
```

What kind of problem do you have with this schema?